# Selecting basins with discharge direction to East using ArcMap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, basin

I have watersheds shapefile created, some discharge their water to the east, others to the west.

Is there is a way to automatically select the ones that discharges to the East using ArcMap 10.3?

Comment: You have three software packages tagged, and no indication of what you have tried or where you are stuck.

Comment: I tried all of them, I did watershed analysis, it ran fine in QGIS/Saga/ArcGIS. now the product is watersheds that discharges the water into either east or west. I am looking for way to automatically select those basins that runs to the East.

Comment: Please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. By specifying several different solution stacks, you are effectively asking multiple questions, which may result in closure for lack of focus. Choose one environment, and show what you have attempted.

Comment: I am asking one question. How to select basins that runs only to the East ?

Comment: ...in QGIS, ArcGIS 10.0, and SAGA

Comment: anything that would do the task? just to get FOCUSED ArcGIS 10.x

Comment: Do you have data on what waterbodies the watersheds discharge into? If so, then you could say something like, "if discharges into Atlantic, return east; if discharges into Pacific, return west" for a very simplistic example. Or could you compare the output point with the geometry of the entire watershed. Something like "if discharge location in the eastern half of the watershed's bounding box, set to east, otherwise set to west". In either case this would probably be a python implementation kind of solution rather than a preexisting tool.

Comment: If you are focusing your question on ArcGIS Desktop then are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I did, Thank you. using ArcGIS desktop 10.3

Comment: "Desktop" encompasses both Pro and ArcMap,  hence Polygeo's request

Comment: I don't understand all fuss around specific software. Though picture can help. Simplistic approach - create fishnet 1 row, 2 columns. If outlet sits in left, western.

Answer (score 0):

I had asked this question before and I solved it in this thread

here is a link

[Drainage divide](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433450/drainage-divide)